# Best way to Handle Login on Android

Tags: android, authentication

Right now I have three activies:

- `HandleActivity`
- `LoginActivity`
- `MainActivity`

When the user opens the app, the `HandleActivity` checks if the users is already logged in, if so it opens the `MainActivity`, if the user is not logged in it opens the `LoginActivity`.

Is there a better way to implement login on Android?

Comment: I don't know that your question is clear enough and is going to draw all opinion based answers. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  


For what you are asking I would recommend taking a look at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/   for your code reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have `HandleActivity`. When user open the app, always show your `MainActivity`. If user isn't logged in, redirect to `LoginActivity`.

```
MainActivity onCreate() {
   if(isLoggedIn)
      loadContent()
   else 
      redirectToLoginActivity()
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I realized I don't need the HandleActivity, instead I've start using the Login Activity as the launcher activity. If the user is logged in, then it goes to the main activity. What do you think about this solution? Do you think is better to have the MainActivity as the launcher activity?

Comment: It's better to have the `MainActivity` as launcher. Because your user probably will need `login` action only once. But they will want to see main content when they open the app. So if you put login activity first, there will be at least 1-2 second delay.

Comment: thank you ozgur gul! Already implemented your solution, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using share preferences then check the share Preferences if data  exist then move to Main Activity else to login activity..
If Using database to store data then check the size of table data

```
   try {
        if (UserdataController.getSingletonInstance().getUserdata(this).size() > 0) {
            Fragment dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framlayout, dashboardFragment);
           // fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("dashboard");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            Fragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framlayout, loginFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){

    }
```